# How to add legend for text in matplotlib？

Tags: python, matplotlib

I put 4 kinds of text in my plot.For example:

```
plt_text = plt.text(_x,_y,"o",color='r',fontsize = 15,label = "Buy")
plt_text = plt.text(_x,_y,"x",color='g',fontsize = 15,lable = "Sell")
```

But plt.legend() can't show the label of texts.How can I solve it?Thx.

I want to add labels for texts,not the figs that plt.plot maked.

Comment: @PeCosta the (only) answer there definitely doesn't apply here.

Comment: Thank you.But ax.text return a Text,example:Text(3523,16.4,'o'),I can't use ax.legend(plt_text,["Buy"]).It seems ax.legend can just work on plot/bar/or else.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Have you tried to add a text artist to a legend? Matplotlib prints a warning which says: "UserWarning: Legend does not support <matplotlib.text.Text object at ...> instances. A proxy artist may be used instead." So clearly PeCosta's comment applies here.

Comment: @PengHe Could you explain why you want to do that? Are you trying to replicate what [plt.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) is doing?

Comment: @hitzg, oh "clearly"?  Well... in that case...  The OP wants to show the text itself as the legend-item, not as the description.  So adding a proxy artist of a different object will *not* solve the problem.  It is a relevant link, and its good that it was shared here, but it is ***clearly*** not a duplicate.

Comment: I drew a line and want to plot some different color points on some position which one kind of color have one meaning. The points is close to the line but not on the line. Finally, I used such as plt.plot(marker = 'o',color = 'k') to instead plt.text, and add legends for plt.plot. But I really want to know how I can add legend for texts.Do you have any ideas?