# Is it possible to use text as the handle in a matplotlib legend entry?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to have a legend entry for annotations on a plot. The annotations start with a certain letter, say 'a' or 'b'. I would like to have an entry in the legend reading:

> a - that sort of annotation

Similar to how other entries are:

> [handle] - [label]

To clarify, unlike [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16826711/7530580) questions where a label is required, **I want the text to be the actual handle.**

I am already creating a custom legend using handles and labels.

Legend refuses a string or a `plt.Text` instance as a handle, returning the warning: `UserWarning: Legend does not support 'a' instances. A proxy artist may be used instead.`

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34125358/7530580) approaches this problem from a different angle, which would work, but it was never answered.

Comment: I gave [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697692/4124317) to the duplicate, which handles the two possible cases of already having a text in the axes, or wanting to create a legend from a string.

Comment: Both are very useful, thank you.